# Benchmarking a Model in Caffe - Does dataset make a difference?

Tags: benchmarking, caffe, conv-neural-network

I use the following command to benchmark my model:

```
./build/tools/caffe time -model /path/to/deploy.prototxt -weights /path/to/caffemodel -gpu all
```

My question is: Does the dataset make any difference? In this case my deploy file does not point to any dataset. Also the caffemodel file should not make a difference even if it is trained for just one epoch. I believe this because the number of multiplications and additions in forward pass will remain the same no matter how trained the model is. Therefore, the benchmark time should be same and accurate regardless of whatever .caffemodel file is used. Is my assumption correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, the dataset doesn't make a difference in the benchmark. Infact, there is no need to give the `-weights` flag even. The `time` functionality uses dummy data for benchmarking the model present in `deploy.prototxt`

Comment: Thank you. I thought the same thing but some useless discussion on the topic made me doubt it.